# gradle: how to combine two tasks with/without a property value set?

Tags: gradle, properties, task

```
gradlew taskOne -Prelease=false
gradlew taskOne -Prelease=true
```

Is there a way to combine them into one? like:

```
task newTask(depends: taskOne[release=false], taskOne[release=true]) {

}
```

Now I can invoke one task:

```
gradlew newTask
```